# Why does dblclick directive of angular not work in IE?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I am surprised why `dblclick` directive of angular is neither working in IE nor in the Edge browser.
This is a piece of my code, really basic:

**HTML**

```
 <select [(ngModel)]="selected"multiple>
            <option *ngFor="let item of filteredData" value="{{ item.id}}"
                (dblclick)="openItem(item)">
                {{item.name}}
            </option>
        </select>
```

**TS**

```
 openItem(item: any) {
    alert('I need this function will be executed when the user will do double click in option')
 }
```

In Chrome and Firefox, it works perfectly.

Comment: what version of edge is this, is it a Edge chromium  browser ?

Comment: And which angular Version you are using?

Comment: improved language.

Comment: IE has had issues with events in select element options since the beginning of time. What is the purpose of clicks in a select? You are going to have to rethink your code here. Has nothing to do with Angular, plenty of questions on stackoverflow about click on options.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event)

> `dblclick` fires after two `click` events (and by extension, after two
>   pairs of `mousedown` and `mouseup` events).

So instead of relying on `dblclick` event, I tried to emulate the double click using `mouseup`. However due to some issue that I am not aware of, it too fails to trigger in Edge.

Template

```
<option *ngFor="let sta of status" [ngValue]="sta" 
  (mouseup)="openItem(sta)" 
  (contextmenu)="openContext($event, sta)">
{{sta}}
</option>
```

Component

```
private clicks = 0;

openItem(item: any) {
  this.clicks++;
  if (this.clicks === 2) {
    this.clicks = 0;
    console.log('Double click: ' + item);
  } else {
    // double click frequency must be less than 300 ms
    setTimeout(() => { this.clicks = 0 }, 300);
  }
}

openContext(event: any, item: any) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Context menu: ' + item);
}
```

So I would say, instead of relying on double click, an alternative would be to use [`contextmenu`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event) event which works as expected across different browsers.

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-example-ngfor-vaq8mt)

Comment: I have tried with the code you give us, it is interesting and I appreciate it.
However, this does not work in IE. I'm in the same situation. Is it possible that it is not yet possible in IE?

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to test in IE since Stackblitz doesn't even open there. However I see from [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=contextmenu) that `contextmenu` event should be available in IE from V9 and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your sample code in IE 11, MS Edge (Chromium), Google Chrome and I got similar results in all browsers. That is your double click event did not get executed.

I am not sure, how it worked on Chrome and Firefox on your side. If possible please describe more about it.

The reason I think that when you first click on the option of the select dropdown then it gets close in no time and selected value gets displayed in Select.

Here I am not aware of your requirement for double click on an option. If possible please provide some more information on it.

I noticed in my test that if we put the double click event on the Select then it is working for all browsers including IE.

Here is a test result with IE 11 browser:

[image]

So you can test and if it serves your purpose then you can use it as a solution for this issue.

Another thing I noticed that if we use Material Select then if you put the event in option code and if you double click the Select then it is working for all browsers.

Sample code:

```
<h4>select Food</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" (dblclick)="openItem(item)" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Let me know if I misunderstand anything, I will try to correct myself.